# POSTing to a Google script with curl results in a 200, but with error in body?

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a script in Google Sheets to add data when being triggered by a POST request. When I submit the data I end up with 200 status, but with an error in the body. When I look at https://script.google.com/ I see no Stackdriver logs or error logs. No data appears in the spreadsheet and adding a `console.log` in the Google script does not output anything. I do see a call in the 'executions' view.

My intent is to have a form in the browser send the request, but due to issues I am testing a simple scenario with curl (URL adjusted):

```
curl -i -L --data-urlencode "email=somedata" \
  https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKgocbzUSKtUZtPVXm4LeQOwpXRqJDOVC9V7Kkma0EmGxUznk7oDL8/exec
```

And here is the response, where we see a 302, followed by a 200 that contains an error:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Sun, 14 Jun 2020 23:33:08 GMT
Location: https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=sSMhQRNsxiFYeVa9f8KhsLtfWwMffTJ1h9VMXxrpx8PZUouQuI81rOpU9HVUNZVinPKB6lVtUnXvJzoLpJmHyaoxHawUxAXur5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnLDPsqfxfo4OXJqB0RHDEqJbiZKd--hAgEdZ96MVkfE8A--R0AVGgjKjTTaUdz1U2Jcdv3aNHr6K&lib=MmofTYKzVaZ_Rz9u3ET07_aEyosnB3VCm
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Sun, 14 Jun 2020 23:33:08 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"result":"error","error":{"name":"Exception"}}%
```

BTW on the issue of the logs, I see them in the script editor when I click on 'view -> logs'. For stack driver logging it asks me to open the 'Apps Script Dashboard'. Here I see logs only when the script is run the editor.

My logging operation is as follows, but I have tried `Logger.log()` as well:

```js
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  console.log(`Received post for ${spreadsheetId}`);
```

When run from the script editor I see something of the form:

```
Jun 15, 2020, 8:39:01 PM    Debug   Received post for 1IzltuWDZ1_4Xm6pdBWePhcUfD8JEyXjHSWLXXkravTMX
```

When the execution is from the web page:

```
No logs are available for this execution
For recent executions there may be some delay in log availability.
```

Trigger settings:

- Choose which function to run: doPost
- Which runs at deployment: Head
- Select event source: From Spreadsheet
- Select event type: On form submit
- Failure notification settings: Notify me daily

Comment: In the case of the Web Apps of Google Apps Script, when it requests to the endpoint of Web Apps of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`, the redirect is run, then, the values from the Google Apps Script are returned. In this case, the status code `200` is returned both with and without the error at Google Apps Script. It seems that this is the current specification.

Comment: About your current situation of `I see no Stackdriver logs or error logs. No data appears in the spreadsheet and adding a console.log in the Google script does not output anything.`, although I'm not sure about your script, if your Google Apps Script occurs no errors, how about redeploying the Web Apps as new version and test it again? By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. If the script has some errors, can you provide your current script for replicating the issue? By this, the modification points might be able to be found.

Comment: So the issue was down to a problem in the script. For runtime, the note on redeploying was useful. Also I now see that only executions from the 'script editor' have logging data associated with them. Still a newbie with Google Scripts.

Comment: @AndreM - actually not, all logs should propagate to the StackDriver logging service. The fact that exceptions are not logged as you claim is troubling. Please, open "File -> Project properties" menu item and check if the checkbox "Log exceptions" is ticked

Comment: @OlegValter it is checked. I just looked

Comment: @AndreM - huh, that is quite strange. Could you please check if a request to `/dev` endpoint ends up in no logs? Also, do you see anything logged here: https://script.google.com/home/projects/`project id`/executions? And, finally, please, could you show us how your `doGet` trigger looks like?

Comment: @OlegValter Please message me via info on GitHub, since we will likely hit the comment limit here.

Comment: There is no limit) If it grows out of hand - it can be moved to chat. What I meant is to update the question - the more context there is, the better it will help others. The fact that "there are no logs" seems implausible once the request hits the endpoint. As you mention that "executions" screen shows that the `doPost` is run, 2 venues remain as I see it: 1. checking `/dev` enpoint. 2. checking what's inside the trigger - it may be relevant. A 3d option would be a bug, but I haven't seen issues on the tracker (although, [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158786750) may be similar).

Comment: Wait a minute - why do you use the `doPost` as callback for a trigger? I thought you deployed it as a web app (and it is the correct way to do it). `onFormSubmit` trigger works only for Google Forms, it is not intended to work with good old html forms. Did you do [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216021/discussion-between-andre-m-and-oleg-valter).

Answer (score 2):

At this point the issue has been resolved. For anyone else:

- The exception most likely points to an error in your script
- Logging was only outputted when the script was run from the script editor

  - There are likely additional setting I didn't set up to get runtime to log, though more can seen in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging).
- Do try running in the script editor first, since it is easier to debug
- Any changes to a script need to a redeploy. Select 'new' as the version in
   the deployment dialogue

In my case, the issue was down to an uninitialised variable in my script, that was breaking things.